# Textarea is not display information extracting from mysql record

Tags: php, mysql, textarea

I am attempting to display data in a `textarea`, I'm using the

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_NUM)
```

to extract the record. Using `$row[2]` displays the correct information using the `p` function. Using the same syntax with textarea does not display anything. The field is not blank in the database. The code does update the field properly.

I have tried changing to change the textarea to a paragraph with no success. I have change the variable by assigning to a new variable without success. I have tried escaping the column and row quotes all to no effect.

```
<?php
echo '<input id="title_edit" type="text" name="ppy" value="'.$row[4].'">'
works

echo '<textarea id=prop_edit cols="65" rows="4" type="text" name="ppy" value="'.$row[7].'"></textarea>'  does not work.
?>
```

Should read the field in the database and display it on the screen. But the screen field is blank. There is data in the database.

Comment: textarea are not like other form inputs you want  `echo '<textarea id=prop_edit cols="65" rows="4" type="text" name="ppy" >'.$row[7].'</textarea>'`

Comment: Yes, you are correct. echoing the variable made the difference. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try:

```
var_dump($row[2]);
```

to make sure it actually has the data I want in it.

Since you don't show how the data is being rendered into html I'll guess it is something like this?

```
echo '<textarea>' . $row[2] . '</textarea>';
```

If so, check the "view source" option in your browser and double check that it is actually outputting what you expect. If the data in $row[2] contains any interesting characters like < or > or anything that resembles an html tag, you might have to escape the output like this:

```
echo '<textarea>' . htmlspecialchars($row[2]) . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: FYI OP had the code in the question, but it was not formatted properly.